# is there a correct way to implement Nextauth with Ionic React v7?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, ionic-framework, native, next-auth

I am currently developing a mobile app with Ionic v7 with React, and I want to know if is it possible to integrate nextauth within the app

I have created my Auth provider, and works just fine at the moment. However, I need to implement new features that nextauth has, so in order of cut some time off, I would like to implements nextauth or any other auth provider on my ionic app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.